# How to install tar.gz file directly from URL efficiently from terminal?

Tags: terminal, install

Suppose we have a web url to a `.tar.gz` file.

We could download it, unzip/tar it, and install it.

Is there an elegant way of doing all of the above from terminal, preferably with a one-liner?

Example tar.gz file: https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz

Note: I don't mind using a program to do this, but much prefer everything done from the terminal, mostly for efficiency, fewer steps, and being able to give reproducible instructions to others

Comment: Is the filename expected to change or will it be the same no matter what?

Comment: @Allan would want to be able to use the same technique for any url to a `.tar.gz` file

Comment: @Allan So yep, i hope for a method that works for any .tar.gz file it receives

Comment: Your second comment answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work better as a script that accepts a parameter.

```
tar_from_url() {
    URL="$1"
    curl -O "$URL"
    tar -xvf "${URL##*/}"
    rm "${URL##*/}"
}
```

So basically use `curl` to download, then use `tar` to extract, finally get rid of downloaded file.

The installation part needs still to be done manually though. The name of the directory it extracts to is unknown and different depending on the actual tar file, as is the method required for installation itself.

Comment: @nohillside This is great and very helpful. But are you sure it's not possible to include the installation in the script? Perhaps some sensible default location?

Comment: @stevec isn't that use case specific ? If it's a pip package say, what purpose would it serve sitting in /usr/local/opt ?

Comment: @ankii I don't know enough to say. I always thought installations had some default locations, but if not, I agree it would not make sense putting it somewhere it cannot be used/accessed

Comment: @stevec The tar file in your example extracts into a directory called `R-3.5.0` (which can be derived from the filename) and afterwards needs `./configure; make; make install` to install. In other cases the directory could have no version number, installation may consist of just `make install` or `sudo cp bin/FOO /usr/local/bin`. If you look for an easy way for this using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is the better approach.

Comment: @nohillside great info, thanks. Can homebrew be provided with a url to a `.tar.gz` ? (i have limited experience with homebrew e.g. `brew install xyz`, but never directly from a url to a `tar.gz`)

Comment: @stevec `brew install R` installs 4.0.0, see https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook for how to write your own formula.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks, I'll have to read up on how brew exactly works. I have a list of `tar.gz` files I shall try to include https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/

Comment: @stevec For a limited set of well-known tar files I probably would just write a bespoke shell script and deploy that.

Comment: @nohillside sounds like that's best. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: @nohillside - thanks for fixing that for me.   If you like, i can delete do you can write up so you can get credit.  You earned it!

Comment: @Allan No worries, all good :-)

Comment: I owe you one @nohillside or at least a few rounds at the pub!  :-)

Comment: @Allan Let's just ignore the fact that a whole planet is between us :-)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to keep the tar file, do

```
curl https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz | tar zxf -
```

This uncompresses and extracts the tar file while downloading it.

The commands to install vary with the package, but you can do this *after* the download has finished:

```
cd R-3.5.0 ; ./configure && make
```

Comment: Since the question was about efficiency, not waiting for the download to complete before starting to unpack, and not taking up disk space for the packed archive, definitely is the way to go.

Comment: One downside of this approach is that if the download failed for any reason, it would have to be restarted from scratch.  (Whereas if it was being downloaded to a file, it could usually be resumed from where it left off.)